Создание списка с условием
Создаю список из строк. В списке надо исключить строки, содержащие 1 или 3. Как исключить строку, содержащую 1 понятно:
non_empty_lines = list(stroka for stroka in spisok_1 if stroka.strip() != '1')

А вот как сделать условие, что бы исключались строки, содержащие 1 или 3?

Например, можно проверять, что пересечение множеств пусто:
if not set(stroka) & set('13')

Ну или "в лоб" объединение условий:
if '1' not in stroka and '3' not in stroka`

А вообще у вас в вопросе проверка не на вхождение символа 1 в строку, а на её равенство 1.
И вызов list у вас избыточен. Вы сначала делаете генератор, и потом уже скармливаете его списку. Проще сразу делать готовый список с помощью списочного включения:
list(...) -> [...]


list(...) и [...] эквивалентны. [] - это синтаксический сахар для более формального list(). Для того, чтобы сначала сделать генератор, а потом скормить его списку, нужно было бы написать: list((generator)), а т.к. автор вопроса записал без двойных скобок, то промежуточного создания генератора нет. list сразу потребляет данные.

@VladimirBogdanov Я даже подумал, что вы правы. Но попробуйте выполнить вот такой код import dis; dis.dis("list(x for x in (1, 2, 3))") и вот такой код import dis; dis.dis("[x for x in (1, 2, 3)]"). Мне выдало там <genexpr> и <listcomp>, и код разный.

@VladimirBogdanov И так то вообще вторые скобки для генератора не обязательны во многих похожих контекстах, достаточно скобок от вызова call того, чем мы обращаемся к генератору. Лишние скобки вообще игнорируются компилятором. В том же кортеже как известно главное не скобки, а запятая. И так во всём. Лишние скобки всегда можно просто выкинуть и ничего не поменяется.

Таки да, списочное включение меньше кода генерирует. Выгоднее его использовать

@VladimirBogdanov Кстати, тут ещё какой аспект. list - это не ключевое слово языка, а всего лишь класс, пусть и встроенный. А значит вы в любой момент можете записать в переменную с именем list что угодно - например, ссылку на свой самописный класс, и Питон это должен успешно обработать "на ходу". Поэтому такая оптимизация, про которую вы подумали, невозможна в Питоне. Он сделает генератор и скормит его через вызов __call__ тому, что лежит в переменной с именем list. Таковы "правила игры". Вот возведение в степень ** он может оптимизировать при желании - это не изменяемая конструкция

Так то в Python вообще все - это классы. Даже примитивные типы int и bool и те классы. На dis никогда не проверял, поверил тому, что в книжках пишут. А тут вон оно как оказывается, Михалыч!

Тьфу, блин, не __call__, а __init__, конечно. __call__ - это когда к экземпляру класса обращаются уже со скобками.

@VladimirBogdanov Ну да. First class objects и всё такое. Очень рекомендую dis, часто интересное показывает.

Кстати, на счет скобок, что они необязательны, это не всегда так. Например, следующий код не будет работать без доп. скобок: lst = [1,2,3,4,5]
m = max((i for i in lst), default=None).  При этом, если параметр default убрать, то скобки становятся не нужны.

@VladimirBogdanov Ну тут то скобки не лишние. Запятая попадает уже внутрь тогда, со скобками и без скобок тут не одно и то же )
